# Unequal indentation in officedown R package

Tags: r, ms-word, r-markdown, officedown

I'm using `officedown` package to generate MS Word documents. I noticed a strange and annoying issue. There are unequal indentation on left and right in the generated output (see the attached picture)

[image]

The Rmarkdown code I use:

```
---
output: officedown::rdocx_document
---

No actual content
```

I open the document with MS Word 2016 (desktop installation).

R sessionInfo output:

```
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Polish_Poland.1250  LC_CTYPE=Polish_Poland.1250    LC_MONETARY=Polish_Poland.1250 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=Polish_Poland.1250    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices datasets  utils     methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_3.3.5    officedown_0.2.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] zip_2.2.0         Rcpp_1.0.8.3      pillar_1.7.0      compiler_4.1.0    tools_4.1.0       digest_0.6.29     uuid_1.0-4       
 [8] evaluate_0.15     memoise_2.0.1     lifecycle_1.0.1   tibble_3.1.6      gtable_0.3.0      pkgconfig_2.0.3   rlang_1.0.2      
[15] DBI_1.1.2         cli_3.2.0         yaml_2.3.5        xfun_0.30         fastmap_1.1.0     withr_2.5.0       dplyr_1.0.8      
[22] officer_0.4.1     stringr_1.4.0     xml2_1.3.3        knitr_1.37        generics_0.1.2    vctrs_0.3.8       gdtools_0.2.4    
[29] systemfonts_1.0.4 tidyselect_1.1.2  grid_4.1.0        glue_1.6.2        R6_2.5.1          rvg_0.2.5         fansi_1.0.2      
[36] rmarkdown_2.13    bookdown_0.25     farver_2.1.0      purrr_0.3.4       magrittr_2.0.2    scales_1.1.1      htmltools_0.5.2  
[43] ellipsis_0.3.2    assertthat_0.2.1  colorspace_2.0-3  renv_0.15.4       labeling_0.4.2    utf8_1.2.2        stringi_1.7.6    
[50] munsell_0.5.0     cachem_1.0.6      crayon_1.5.0
```

When I use `bookdown::word_document2` as the output the issue is gone, so I expect there is something wrong with `officedown` package. However, the author doesn't allow new issues on GitHub.

I checked the default settings for page size and margins and they seem to be fine, i.e. margins are equal on both sides.

My first question is can you reproduce the strange behavior of officedown (I tested it on two different machines and in docker container, but MS Word 2016 only)? The second question - can it be fixed somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the margins you want to use (see `?rdocx_document` argument `page_margins`):

```
---
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
author: "Your Name"
title: "officedown template"
output: 
  officedown::rdocx_document:
    page_margins:
      bottom: .75
      top: .75
      right: 1
      left: 1
      header: 0.5
      footer: 0.5
      gutter: 0
---
```

Github issues are closed, instead users are invited to open discussions https://github.com/davidgohel/officedown/discussions

See https://github.com/davidgohel/officedown#questions-and-issues

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you tell why the indents are unequal by default? It seems to be a bug.

Comment: The gutter has a default value of 0.5 because it's mapped to the default values of `officer::page_mar`, it's been a long time since this is as it is, I don't remember why the default value of 0.5. As you can see in my answer, you can change this value to 0 in the `page_margins` section of the yaml header. I can change default gutter to 0, I don't really care (I usually avoid printing documents)

Comment: I think it'd be good if you changed the default value of gutter to 0, because now it's confusing. Thanks for clarification and reasons behind of it.